Why am I unable to change position of shapes in VBA
The following subroutine imports pictures and textboxes from a source Worksheet to a target Worksheet. The target worksheet is in the Active workbook, but not necessarily the ActiveSheet. The source Worksheet is in another (open) Workbook. The Shapes are copied successfully, but changing their position has no effect. The target Worksheet is protected, but unprotecting it has no effect.
Sub importShapes(target As Worksheet, source As Worksheet)
    Dim sourceShape As Shape
    For Each sourceShape In source.Shapes
        If sourceShape.Type = msoPicture Or sourceShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
            sourceShape.Copy
            target.Paste
           
            Dim targetShape As Shape
            Set targetShape = target.Shapes(target.Shapes.Count) ' the shape just added
            
            targetShape.top = sourceShape.top
            targetShape.left = sourceShape.left
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Working fine for me

The problem comes from assuming that target.Shapes.Count is the index of the shape that was just pasted.  The target worksheet has a cell with data validation based on a list, and the little button on the list is a  shape (msoShapeType = 8)., so target.Shapes(target.Shapes.Count) points at this form control. I need a better way to select the shape just added.

Make a list of all shape Id's on the target sheet, then start the copy process - after each paste find the shape with an id which is not in the list: that's the one you just added.

Since the shape just pasted is selected, this works:   Set targetShape = Selection.ShapeRange(1)

Here's one possible approach:
Sub Tester()
    importShapes ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet4"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
End Sub


Sub importShapes(Target As Worksheet, source As Worksheet)
    Dim sourceShape As Shape, ids As String, shp As Shape, i As Long
    
    ids = "|"
    For Each shp In Target.Shapes 'collect all existing shape id's
        ids = ids & shp.id & "|"
    Next shp
    
    For Each sourceShape In source.Shapes
        If sourceShape.Type = msoPicture Or sourceShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
            sourceShape.Copy
            Target.Paste
            
            Dim targetShape As Shape
            Set targetShape = Target.Shapes(Target.Shapes.Count)
            
            For i = Target.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1 'find the pasted shape
                Set shp = Target.Shapes(i)
                If InStr(ids, "|" & shp.id & "|") = 0 Then 'new id?
                    Set targetShape = shp    'newly-added
                    ids = ids & shp.id & "|" 'add to list
                End If
            Next i
            If Not targetShape Is Nothing Then 'got new shape?
                targetShape.top = sourceShape.top
                targetShape.Left = sourceShape.Left
            Else
                Debug.Print "no target shape"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub


I found a simpler solution. Since the shape just pasted onto the target worksheet is currently selected, this works: Set targetShape = Selection.ShapeRange(1)

That does require the Target sheet to be active though...

Yes, as I found out. I added a call to target.Activate
